# UE 4.25 - Can't create EQS assets

Tags: unreal-4

Like the title says I am unable to create EQS assets. I am running 4.25 and there is no option in the BT details panel, nor under "Add assets -> AI". AND there is no option to activate it. Neither under settings or under plugin. Nothing.

What am I doing wrong? See screenshots and thanks in advance
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in `Editor Settings / Experimental`, as per documentation ([EQS Quick Start](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/ArtificialIntelligence/EQS/EQSQuickStart/index.html)):

[image: official screenshot]

Here is my own screenshot from `4.25.4`:

[image: my screenshot]